# Count on DF gives different result

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am creating a `df` from an XML file and doing some joins with another file. Whenever I do the count of a resulting DF from a join query, it gives me different count.I am not caching the data. It's looking like a weird behavior of spark.
Any idea why this happens? This is what am doIng ...

```
val file1 = sqlContext.sql("select * from infile2");
file1.registerTempTable("file1");
val file2 = sqlContext.sql("select * from infile2");
file2.registerTempTable("file2");
val joinedfile = sqlContext.sql("select * from file1 join file2 on file1.id = file2.id");
```

Now,

```
joinedfile.count()
```

gives different count every time whenever I run it.

Comment: sharing your code, that would help in better understanding of your problem

Comment: @p2. an update , the count is differing with the resulting DF of a join query . I will share the code too.

Comment: what version of Spark?

Comment: @marios spark 1.6.2 on azure .

Comment: Does your underlining file changes?

Comment: @marios no. the file does not change during the code run.

Comment: @vds where you able to find the problem?